# Why do I get a '403 (Forbidden)' error with Dajaxice?

Tags: django, dajaxice

I just installed Dajaxice, but I keep having this error:

```
POST https://.../communication.isUserLogged/ 403 (Forbidden) dajaxice.core.js:163
Dajaxice: Something went wrong.
```

on the server side:

```
"POST /dajaxice/communication.isUserLogged/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2282
```

I guess the server does not get the correct CSRF token, but I don't know how to fix the problem.

Dajaxice documentation says

> Ensure that TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS has django.core.context_processors.request.

but [it is set by default in Django 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/).
I still get this warning:

> The 'request' object must be accesible within the context. You must add 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.request' to your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS and render your views using a RequestContext.

Here is my code: https://c9.io/arthursw/brain

Comment: I cannot access your code but it seems you are using a `Context` instead of a `RequestContext` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) in your views.

Comment: Here is my view.py file: `def index(request):
 return render(request, 'index.html')`. Is it valid?

Comment: yes, it is. By default, the template will be rendered with a RequestContext instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [Django's API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/) (see also [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#template-context-processors)) `django.core.context_processors.request` is not set by default:

> By default, TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS is set to:

```
("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages")
```

> In addition to these, RequestContext always uses django.core.context_processors.csrf.

AFTER DISCUSSION...

then, at the very end, you have just to add the following line at the end of your settings file:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + ( 'django.core.context_processors.request', )
```

Comment: I added `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.request',
)` in settings.py, and now I get: `ImproperlyConfigured at /
Module "django.contrib.messages.context_processors" does not define a "request" callable request processor`

Comment: are you sure you are running Django 1.5.x?

Comment: yes: `>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 5, 0, 'final', 0)`

Comment: does the same error occurs if you define TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in this way: `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ( 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.request', ) + global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` (i.e. changing the order of processors)?

Comment: do you use messages framework in your project? if not, please try removing `django.contrib.messages.context_processors` from `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS ` (ok, not a real solution, the problem is elsewhere, but just trying to reduce the possible variables)

Comment: same thing: when I don't have `django.contrib.messages.context_processors.request` I get 403 errors, otherwise I get `"django.contrib.messages.context_processors" does not define a "request" callable request processor`

Comment: So in that case you get a 403 Forbidden... Then I believe the error is somewhere else, in your previous code (unrelated to Dajaxice). Sorry I've no idea how to solve the problem with the information in my possess.

Comment: Ok, I managed to export my project in Koding, can you see my code with this link https://koding.com/Teamwork?sessionKey=arthurmasson_fute_12 ? I asked cloud9 to fix the bug to be able to share my code from cloud9, but no answer so far.

Comment: you have to add **`django.core.context_processors.request`** not `django.contrib.messages.context_processors.request`! My apologizes I haven't noticed you mentioned that context processor, not the right one before.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44247/discussion-between-arthur-sw-and-furins)